# SQL : How to get string that appears after first or second space in DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column that has multiple spaces I have to select specific value

| My Column |
| --- |
| South Africa ABC |
| Hong Kong XYZ |
| America ABC |
| Q&RS China |
| Other |

I would like to have following result

| New Column |
| --- |
| ABC |
| XYZ |
| ABC |
| Q&RS |
| Other |

This means I just need to pull values after first second spaces and before the first space appears

I have used patindex in my substring , but I get something like this

| Actual Column |
| --- |
| Africa ABC |
| Kong XYZ |
| china |
| Other |

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Please explain the result in the fourth row.  It is not consistent.

Comment: it should not be China , it should be Q&RS

Comment: `Q&RS China` and `America ABC` are syntactically equal. Why `Q&RS` but `ABC` ?

Comment: that refers to a business code which needs to extracted in to seperate columns
ABC
Q&RS
XYZ
Other

Comment: You need kind of a special data source to tell why the first word from `Q&RS China` but the second word from `America ABC`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the reference to `patindex()`, I'm going to assume this is SQL Server.  I am also guessing that the fourth row should really be China, based on the rule you describe.

You can look for the first space in the reversed string -- and add one there if necessary.  Then just take characters from the end:

```
select v.*,
       right(v.str, charindex(' ', reverse(v.str) + ' ') - 1)
from (values ('South Africa ABC'),
             ('Hong Kong XYZ'),
             ('America ABC'),
             ('Q&RS China'),
             ('Other')
     ) v(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML and XQuery to tokenize a string.
XML and XQuery data model is based on ordered sequences. Exactly what we need for your scenario.

Overall, we are taking a last token in the space separated sequence of tokens/words via XPath `[last()]` predicate.

Additionally, I introduced a business rule to filter out the 'China' token. That business rule was not explicitly specified. That's why I took a liberty here.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl table (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('South Africa ABC'),
('Hong Kong XYZ'),
('America ABC'),
('Q&RS China'),
('Other');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
    , TRY_CAST('<root><x><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, SPACE(1), ']]></x><x><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></x></root>' AS XML)
    .value('(/root/x[./text()!="China"][last()]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS result
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------+--------+
| ID |      tokens      | result |
+----+------------------+--------+
|  1 | South Africa ABC | ABC    |
|  2 | Hong Kong XYZ    | XYZ    |
|  3 | America ABC      | ABC    |
|  4 | Q&RS China       | Q&RS   |
|  5 | Other            | Other  |
+----+------------------+--------+
```